# ASP.MVC Intranet and Internet Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I am curious about if MVC4 or MVC 5 supports a feature such that, my application will be accessible via internet and users will be able to login which i can use some membership provider, then same application is available via intranet that users won't need to login ie will be authenticated via AD or if they are in domain no authentication will be required.

Is this possible? is there a built in functionality for this ?

Comment: I don't think there is any built in functionality. We had the same challenge in one of our projects and had to do a lot more to get both these types of logins work.

Comment: well there is a built in functionality for each. `AccountController` for internet and something for intranet. Not sure if i can use both in same project. How did you handle ?

Comment: I suppose you could create a deploy two different versions of the application; one intranet one internet.  Not ideal but the common code could be moved to a library.  But not don't believe there is any built in support for this.

Comment: We did not find a perfect way to do this. As I remember we had a custom principal which worked with FormsAuthentication, plus we had a landing page to check if the users windows identity is valid else redirect the user to a login page. I do not have to code handy so just trying to recollect what we did like a year back. Let me see if I can get the code.

Comment: Thanks. appreaciate your time

Answer (score -1):

If you use

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

in your web.config file you have exactly that comportment